# Can't Import psycopg2._psycopg Inside a docker

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, docker, psycopg2

I am trying to build a docker image with the following requirement.txt file
but when I call my python function, there is a part that calls to a redshift database to perform query and extract data, then I get an error :

> ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libresolv-2-c4c53def.5.so: symbol __res_maybe_init version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference

```
python-dateutil==2.6.0
numpy==1.12.0
jsonschema==2.6.0
pandas==0.20.3
python-consul==0.7.2
boto==2.49.0
datadog==0.15.0
invoke==1.4.1
SQLAlchemy==1.1.5
graypy==0.2.14
llvmlite==0.31.0
fastparquet==0.2.1
simple-salesforce==0.74.2
pytz==2019.1
psycopg2==2.7.1
```

My docker file is :

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV COLLECTION aa
ENV TASK_PARAMS aa
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev

WORKDIR /opt/airflow_repository
ADD analytics ./analytics
ADD FrameworkPY ./FrameworkPY
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONPATH ${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/airflow_repository/similarweb_analytics
ENV INI_ENVIRONMENT_SETTINGS_PATH=/etc/


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD invoke -c $COLLECTION mainrun $TASK_PARAMS
```

after building the docker image I am trying to run a python script that read data from my redshift :
Using the following cmd :
docker run -it  -e COLLECTION=/opt/airflow_repository/ods/sf/sf_to_ods -e TASK_PARAMS="--job-type /opt/airflow_repository/ods/sf/configs/sf_contact_delta.json" airflow_bidev

i get the following error traceback :

```
pid 6 - 2020-04-29 20:34:27,083 - INFO - sf_to_ods.py - run - line 60 - starting sf_to_ods
Setting value
pid 6 - 2020-04-29 20:34:27,087 - INFO - consul_connections.py - get_connection_settings - line 15 - retrieving general_settings connection settings from consul
pid 6 - 2020-04-29 20:34:28,412 - INFO - consul_connections.py - get_connection_settings - line 15 - retrieving sf connection settings from consul
pid 6 - 2020-04-29 20:34:29,003 - INFO - consul_connections.py - get_connection_settings - line 15 - retrieving etl connection settings from consul
pid 6 - 2020-04-29 20:34:29,314 - ERROR - sf_to_ods.py - run - line 165 - /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libresolv-2-c4c53def.5.so: symbol __res_maybe_init version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/invoke", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(program.run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 384, in run
    self.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/invoke/program.py", line 566, in execute
    executor.execute(*self.tasks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/invoke/executor.py", line 129, in execute
    result = call.task(*args, **call.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/invoke/tasks.py", line 127, in __call__
    result = self.body(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//opt/airflow_repository/similarweb_analytics/ods/sf/sf_to_ods.py", line 244, in mainrun
    run(**module_config_)
  File "/opt/airflow_repository/FrameworkPY/vbi_utils/decorating_utils.py", line 89, in wrapped_func
    res = func(*args, **utils.get_config_dict_from_path(**kwargs))
  File "/opt/airflow_repository/FrameworkPY/vbi_utils/decorating_utils.py", line 100, in wrapped_func
    res = func(*formatted_args, **formatted_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow_repository/FrameworkPY/vbi_utils/decorating_utils.py", line 79, in wrapped_func
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//opt/airflow_repository/similarweb_analytics/ods/sf/sf_to_ods.py", line 70, in run
    kwargs = results_container.get_increment(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow_repository/similarweb_analytics/results_container/results_container.py", line 342, in get_increment
    kwargs.update(inc_util.get_from_val(**kwargs))
  File "/opt/airflow_repository/similarweb_analytics/sw_utils/increment_utils.py", line 25, in get_from_val
    if not kv.get(**kwargs):
  File "/opt/airflow_repository/FrameworkPY/fw_utils/key_val.py", line 80, in get
    engine_ = alch_engine.create_engine(config_.get(DB_ENGINE))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 387, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 80, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 554, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libresolv-2-c4c53def.5.so: symbol __res_maybe_init version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update `psycopg2` to atleast `2.7.3.1` avoid compatibility issues with  glibc 2.26

from [release notes](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/news.html#what-s-new-in-psycopg-2-7-3-1)

> Dropped libresolv from wheel package to avoid incompatibility with
>   glibc 2.26 (wheels ticket #2).